# how to emit event on nuxt-socket.io from client to server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sockets, socket.io, nuxt.js

im learning to use Nuxt in the past i have worked with socket.io and vue but this time i am using nuxt-socket-io
https://nuxt-socket-io.netlify.app/

My problem is that I cannot send events from client to server

here an example:

in socket-io-server.js

```
io.emit ("eventTry")
```

at homepage.vue

```
mounted () {

     this.socket = this. $ nuxtSocket ({
       name: "main",
     });

     this.socket.on ("eventTry", () => {
         console.log ("this Work Good");
     })

   },
```

**and this works fine**

but when I try to **send from the client to the server nothing works example:**

at homepage.vue

```
this.socket.emit ("eventTryClient");
```

and in socket-io-serve.js:

```
io.on ("eventTryClient", () => {
         console.log ("something should happen here")
     })
```

**and this DONT WORK**

I've really looked everywhere and I can't find a solution to this problem that should be so simple, could someone help me? I need to have a bidirectional communication, which is the best of socket.io I think

Thanks in advance for your help <3

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for events **on the socket**. Listening on a namespace, e.g. your `io` variable, won't actually listen to events sent by the client. More info [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/listening-to-events/), *although it doesn't explicitly state to listen on the client socket.*

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where I saw this solution, but I will share it because surely there is someone else who is interested in this... The only thing necessary to establish the connection between client and server is the following:

in your client (example homepage.vue):

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
const ioClient = io.connect("http://localhost:3001"); // replace it with the url of your socket
```

The URL it's in nuxt.config.js, and you probably have something like this:

```
 // socket.io configuration
  io: {
    sockets: [{
      default: true, // make this the default socket
      name: 'main', // give it a name that we can later use to choose this socket in the .vue file
      url: 'http://localhost:3001' // URL wherever your socket IO server runs
    }]
  },
```

With this you can use ioClient as your connection on the client for example:

```
 ioClient.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("socket-io-client conected")
    ioClient.emit('chatmessage', this.message); //now this works and you can receive it on your server normally
 })
```

I dont know if this is the better way to do that, but i dont really saw solutions for this in the documentation ... maybe im blind, or no body answer that